# Biblatex: small caps for pages in roman numerals

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

In Biblatex I can use roman numerals in the pages fiels and in the citation commands.
E.g.:

```
@InBook{id,
author    = {Surname, Name},
title     = {Title},
booktitle = {Book Title},
date      = {2000},
pages     = {x-cx},
```

}

or:

```
\footcite[xc]{id}
```

I'd like to print the pages numbers in small caps. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can get Roman page numbers in `biblatex` to appear in small caps.

First we define a macro `\mknormrangescromannums` that detects if a given number is a Roman numeral and applies additional formatting in that case. The test for Roman numerals is based on the other numeral tests of `biblatex` (`\ifinteger`, `\ifnumeral`, `\ifnumerals`, ...).

Then we use the `<itempostpro>` argument of `\mknormrange` (introduced in `biblatex` 3.13 [2019-08-17]) to call `\mknormrangescromannums` on all page numbers.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@hook@ifromannum{%
  \def\do##1{\uccode`##1=`\%}%
  \do\i\do\v\do\x\do\l\do\c\do\d\do\m
  \do\I\do\V\do\X\do\L\do\C\do\D\do\M}

\protected\def\blx@imc@ifromannumeral{%
  \blx@ifnum\blx@hook@ifromannum}

\blx@regimcs{\ifromannumeral}
\makeatother

\newrobustcmd*{\smallcapsromannums}[1]{%
  \ifromannumeral{#1}
    {\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}
    {#1}}

\newcommand*{\mknormrangescromannums}{\mknormrange[][\smallcapsromannums]}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrangescromannums]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination][\mknormrangescromannums]{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InBook{id,
  author    = {Surname, Name},
  title     = {Title},
  booktitle = {Book Title},
  date      = {2000},
  pages     = {x-cx},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite[xxi]{id}

\autocite[12-45]{id}

\autocite[hello]{id}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Surname 2000, p. xxi) with 'xxi' in small caps]

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible: add this code to your preamble to define the `scroman` numbering:

```
\makeatletter
    \def\scroman#1{\expandafter\@scroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@scroman#1{{\scshape\romannumeral #1}}
\makeatother
```

If needed, we also can define a  `scosroman` numbering, same as the above, except that a number such as `xviii` (several final `i`s) is printed as `xviij`, i.e. the final i is replaced with a (smallcaps) j.